# Defining variable using conditional operation in javascript

Tags: javascript

`name = name || {}` throws a reference error whereas `var name = name || {}` works. How does javascript variable initialization work?

Comment: Useful reading: [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
var name = name || {};
```

is really interpreted like this:

```
// Upon entry to the scope
var name;

// Later, in step-by-step code
name = name || {}
```

Since `name` is declared, you can get its value (have `name` on the right-hand side of the `=`) safely. Its value will be `undefined` at that point, so `name = name || {}` will assign `{}` to it.

The big difference here:

```
name = name || {}
```

...is that you don't have any declaration for `name`, and so it doesn't exist as of when the right-hand of that assignment is evaluated. [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) lets you *create* global variables implicitly by assigning to them, but doesn't allow you to *read* the value of a variable that doesn't exist (yet).

That's why the version with `var` works and the version without throws the `ReferenceError`.

---

Side note: I recommend not relying on the horror of implicit globals. Instead, always declare your variables (and avoid globals whenever possible). You can use JavaScript's "strict mode" to turn the horror of implicit globals into a `ReferenceError` (e.g., writing to an unknown symbol becomes an error rather than creating a global, just like reading one does).

Answer (score 2):

Second code works because of JavaScript Hoisting.

When you have

```
var name = name || {}
```

It gets arranged like

```
//moved to to top of scope
var name;

//point where you initialize it
name = name || {};
```

So when you initialize name, it is already declared and having value of `undefined`. First code hasnt got name declared.

Answer (score 0):

`name = name || {}` says "I already have a variable called `name`, set it to either `name` or `{}`. The problem is that you **don't** already have a variable called name. Thus when it skips on to see what it should be set to, it thinks "aha, `name` ... oh wait, it's not set" and errors.

`var name = ...` creates the variable first, and then starts looking to see what it should be, so when it gets to evaluating the value, it says "aha, `name` ... i just made that, it's undefined. That's falsey, so it's an `{}`".

There are two other common situations this arises in.

```
function a(name) { name = name || 'Joe'; }
```

where if `name` isn't passed in (eg. `a()`) it will default to Joe. In this case, the variable has already been defined by the function definition, so you don't need the `var`.

```
defaults = { name: 'Joe' };
options = {};

// Later on
options.name = options.name || defaults.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `var` javascript define all varables in the beginning of the scope.
That's called varable hoisting.

For example if you have this code:

```
function doStuff() {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++)
      var currentItem = arr[i]
      var doSomething = function(currentItem) { ... }
   }
}
```

javascript execute this code:

```
function doStuff() {
   var i,
       currentItem,
       doSomething;

   for (i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
      currentItem = arr[i]
      doSomething = function(currentItem) {...}
   }
}
```